# What is the best practice for CI development?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, nexus

We are starting to develop `CI` workflow for our systems in my company.

Currently we just making few basic tasks like build, tests, and upload to `Nexus`.

The tech stack is a Java project which build in `Gradle` and `Jenkins` makes our build.

Currently i'm working with some basic `Groovy` script to make what we need, but each time i'm copy and paste my updated code to `Jenkins` and running the job from `Jenkins` UI to see the results, and to me it seems like not a very good approach for developing such automation code.

My question is, what is the best practice to build and run `Jenkins` jobs?

- Is it possible to run it straight from `Intellij` ?
- Do we need to create a `Jenkins` project which should be saved as a repository and then deploy it to `Jenkins` machine?
- Do we need to use some `Intellij` plugins in order to work with `Jenkins`?

More best practices are welcome :)

Comment: Best practices questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they are primarily opinion-base.d

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has an API - so you can do whatever you want!

But in general, for small to medium teams it's better to use [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and let Jenkins pull code changes (or pull-requests) from SCM and trigger builds. You can also configure hooks to trigger builds if your SCM supports this (Github & bitbucket supports this).

If you are eventually pushing your artifacts to a docker image, I would highly recommend docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

If you are completely new to CI/CD stuff - Atlassian has a lot of good resources https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/principles/continuous-integration-vs-delivery-vs-deployment

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What about development from `Intellij`, do we need to use some project which is type of Jenkins or just use the API ?

Comment: Have you looked into https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6110-jenkins-control-plugin ? I would recommend you to only commit & push from your IDE. And the rest should be taken care by automation.